# Interpolation gone awry?

Tags: interpolation

Here's a simple example of an interpolation function that seems to me to have gone awry. Maybe someone would be so kind as to tell my what's going on with this?

```
tst2 = {{0, 0}, {0.0057269`, 0.2`}, {0.0366617`, 0.4`}, {0.158682`, 
    0.6`}, {0.50688`, 0.8`}, {0.938627`, 1.`}};

MatrixForm[tst2]
fx = Interpolation[tst2];
Plot[fx[x], {x, 0.0, 0.9}]
```

\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0.0057269 & 0.2 \\
 0.0366617 & 0.4 \\
 0.158682 & 0.6 \\
 0.50688 & 0.8 \\
 0.938627 & 1. \\
\end{array}

[image: Plot of fx[x]]

Comment: All: I know there is a Q&A that already describes the algorithm used by `Interpolation` that I believe would explain this apparently strange behavior, but I cannot find it.  Does anyone recall?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/how-does-interpolation-really-work ?

Comment: @Young Thanks!  I also found this possible duplicate: [(104037)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104037/121)

Comment: The data doesn't behave much like a polynomial. Perhaps a power law fit will do? Behavior is close to `x^.3`

Comment: The suggested vertical asymptote at zero indicates working with the inverse function may be better behaved.

Comment: @Eric, surely you meant "tangent" instead of "asymptote", no?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that any `InterpolationOrder` greater than 1 using the default method (Hermite) yields an unsatisfactory curve.

Maybe a simple regression fit would suit your purposes:

```
tst2 = {{0.0057269, 0.2},{0.0366617, 0.4},{0.158682, 0.6},{0.50688, 0.8}, {0.938627, 1.}};
model = a x^b;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[tst2, model, {a, b}, x];
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0.00, 1}, Epilog -> Point[tst2]]
```

[image]

or a more complicated fit:

```
tst2 = {{0, 0}, {0.0057269, 0.2}, {0.0366617, 0.4}, 
        {0.158682, 0.6}, {0.50688, 0.8}, {0.938627, 1.}};
model = a x^(3/2) - b x + c x^(1/2) + d;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[tst2, model, {a, b, c, d}, x];
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0.00, 1}, Epilog -> Point[tst2]]
```

[image]

Example of Method "Spline" at the same order as the default.

```
fx = Interpolation[tst2, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
Plot[fx[x], {x, 0.0, 1.0}, Epilog -> Point[tst2]]
```

[image]

Interpolation Reference:

[How does Interpolation really work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/how-does-interpolation-really-work)

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? I am having trouble duplicating your results in V10.4.1

Comment: Same version, Windows-64bit ... Which graph?

Comment: The simple, first one. I'm getting an error message and no evaluation.

Comment: As shown in the answer, I deleted point {0,0} for the simple fit ... {0,0} isn't used in the data set for the last graph either.

Comment: Ah, so. I failed to notice that. Interestingly, `NonlinearModelFit[tst2, {a x^b, 0 < b <= .5}, {a, b}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]` works with the original data and gives the same fit as yours.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps linear interpolation will suit your needs:

```
fx2 = Interpolation[tst2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[fx2[x], {x, 0.0, 0.9}, Epilog -> Point[tst2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using the [Steffen monotonic interpolation](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990A%26A...239..443S) routine from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14040):

```
tst2 = {{0, 0}, {0.0057269, 0.2}, {0.0366617, 0.4}, {0.158682, 0.6},
        {0.50688, 0.8}, {0.938627, 1.}};
fx = SteffenInterpolation[tst2];

Plot[fx[x], {x, 0.0, 0.9}]
```

[image: plot of Steffen interpolant]

Comment: (N.B. [Fritsch-Carlson](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11859) will also work here.)

Comment: It's nice to know there even exist such types of interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

This makes a good fit and includes the point at zero.

```
data = 
  {{0, 0}, {0.0057269, 0.2}, {0.0366617, 0.4}, {0.158682, 0.6}, {0.50688, 0.8},
   {0.938627, 1.}};
Clear[fx]
fx =
  NonlinearModelFit[data, {a x^b, 0 < b <= .5}, {a, b}, x, 
    Method -> "NMinimize"]["Function"]
```

> `1.0077 #1^0.293795 &`

```
Plot[fx[x], {x, 0., 1.},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Scaled[.01]], Point[data]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Now that I think about it, OP could probably clarify if what he wants is a fit or an interpolant, as those do different things.

Comment: @J.M. Good point, but there a 3rd position on the matter: doesn't care which. Perhaps you make a query to the OP on this as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment about inverse functions, a simple implementation ...

```
tst2 = {{0, 0}, {0.0057269`, 0.2`}, {0.0366617`, 0.4`}, {0.158682`, 0.6`}, {0.50688`, 0.8`}, {0.938627`, 1.`}};
ifx = Interpolation[Reverse /@ tst2];
fx = InverseFunction[FunctionInterpolation[ifx[y], {y, 0, 1}]];
Plot[fx[x], {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Point[tst2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]