# Interpolation does not give continued function

Tags: interpolation

I am trying to interpolate experimental data. everything seems to work well but the function is not Continuous. Any idea why?

```
      points = {{3.330818438, 0.0003038113938}, {3.784353004, 
0.0001138139260}, {4.299642242, 0.0000171648834}, {4.885094861, 
8.811442171*^-7}, {5.550264523, 5.241290068*^-9}};
g = Interpolation[points]
Show[LogPlot[g[x], {x, 3.4, 6}], ListLogPlot[points]]
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate: [Interpolation function way off](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104037/5478), that is, is this acceptable: `g = Interpolation[MapAt[Log, #, {All, 2}] &@points];
Show[LogPlot[E^g[x], {x, 3.4, 6}, PlotRange -> Full], 
 ListLogPlot[points]]`?

Comment: I think it is so I will link it, let me know if you disagree.